# Polygon drawing

Tags: c#, .net

I want the user to define a polygon by using his mouse and clicks to define the points. The second task is once i have a set of defined polygons i want to check if some randomly generated points lie within any of those polygons.

I am working on C# .net platform. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a good goal.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your question makes it look like you haven't even tried to do it yourself - I'm sure you have but you should give us some detail about what you've tried and we'll try to get you on the right path.

Comment: I have thought about the approach though not exactly tried it yet because am not sure of the methods that can be used. Well am thinking of storing the points in a list. Then using the list elements to define a polygon. Then checking if a particular point is within the various polygons. Isnt there any inbuilt function that checks if a point lies in a polygon,VC++ had one such.Convex and concave is not a issue because the polygon would be defined by the order in which user defines them. Thanks..

Comment: If VC++ had one then you could easily PInvoke to the VC++ function.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a simple task. For instance, you should analyze and sort the set of points as Convex or Concave Hull. You can use the following links as resources:

http://ubicomp.algoritmi.uminho.pt/local/concavehull.html

http://marknelson.us/2007/08/22/convex/

[Is there an efficient algorithm to generate a 2D concave hull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83593/is-there-an-efficient-algorithm-to-generate-a-2d-concave-hull)

http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.854/06/scribe/s26-randomIC.pdf

http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0109/algorithm_0109.htm

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but straight forward solution. This is actually pretty simple if you make full use of the Graphics and Drawing2D namespaces.

[GraphicsPath.AddLines( Point[] )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkh85f05%28v=vs.90%29)

[Graphics.DrawPath( Drawing2D.GraphicsPath )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawpath%28v=vs.90%29)

[Graphics.FillPath( Drawing2D.GraphicsPath )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fillpath%28v=vs.90%29)

[GraphcisPath.CloseFigure( )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.closefigure%28v=vs.90%29)

So you'd simply create a new path, then call AddLines passing your array of points, and then call CloseFigure.

If you want to stroke it with a pen, use DrawPath. If you want to fill it with a brush, use FillPath.

Hit test for any points inside the polygon is simple as well, you would use [Drawing.Region( Drawing2D.GraphicsPath )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.region_members%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and any overload of [Region.IsVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.region.isvisible%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that allows you to specify a position and graphics object.