# How divide self-intersecting polygon into simple polygons?

Tags: algorithm

I have one polygon defined by list of points. This polygon can be self-intersecting with more than one point of intersection. I found all points by brute-force. (Bentley-Ottmann sweep method not implemented yet). For example, 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/da4dZ.png
i have 4 vertices and edge 1-2 intersect with edge 4-0 (point A) and edge 2-3 intersect with edge 4-0 (point B). I heve simple polygon 0-1-A-0 and rest, this rest also divide to two polygons: A-B-2-A
and B-3-4-B
How is general algortithm?

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward approach is to compute a [planar straight-line graph (PSLG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_straight-line_graph) by subdividing the polygon segments at points of intersection (Bentley--Ottmann naturally extends to do this simultaneously), then enumerate its finite faces. The latter can be accomplished by preparing a combinatorial embedding and then [traversing it as described in this previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103138/find-the-outline-of-adjacent-polygons/26189674#26189674).