# contour edges determined by points in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapes, contour

I was wondering if there is a way to get the shape of the contour of a region determined by several points. For instance, in the image below, I show as a background (in gray) a collection of points, but it does not look very nice, so I would like to determine automatically what are the edges or the contour that the points are delimiting, to just plot the shape of the background instead of plotting thousands of points to show it.

[image]

Edit: As kindly pointed out by @heltonbiker, actually the \chi-shape in http://www.geosensor.net/papers/duckham08.PR.pdf would perfectly do the job, however I still have no clue on how to implement it. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an efficient algorithm to generate a 2D concave hull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83593/is-there-an-efficient-algorithm-to-generate-a-2d-concave-hull)

Comment: There is a python implementation in [this blogpost](http://blog.thehumangeo.com/2014/05/12/drawing-boundaries-in-python/), and another in [this notebook](https://gist.github.com/perrette/127e9de3b0f905dc8ef2882d4d5768f8).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  great, that is actually what I was looking for. Thank you very much!